# Report Viewer not Stopping Stored Procedure on window close

Tags: sql-server-2008, stored-procedures, report, reportviewer

I am using Report Viewer 2008 to generate a report which uses a Stored Procedure (SQL Server 2008) to populate it. The report generates properly. This reports take a while to generate as it is large. During loading of the report if a user closes the browser window this stored procedure keeps executing until it is finished (even though no report is showed...). The issue is that this kills the server processor especially if this is done by multiple users and once closed they reopen and load again causing the Stored Procedure to run twice similtaneously by the same user.

Is there anyway to force the stored procedure to stop executing once the browser is closed? Thank you in advance for the help!!

Comment: Well apperantely there is no fix to this... Heres a reference i found... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1305200/stored-proc-and-program-are-still-running-even-though-browser-is-closed

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at DBCommand.Cancel()

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.cancel.aspx

You can register on the CloseEvent of the form where your report is displayed and when the form is closing, try to cancel the statement as well.

Comment: Im running the reports off a report server. Theres no form in which i can access a close event from. any other ideas?

Comment: I see, sorry I thought it was a WindowsForms application. I don't have other idea... Do you have any control in the browser? If you can add a javascript there, you could register on the leave event and at least you will catch the visitors leaving/closing the browser window.

Comment: Unfortunately theres no code involved because it access the rdl files directly so i have no way of inserting any code to stop the SP. :(